# Compact, extremely disconnected spaces of weight $\omega_1$

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

**Weight** of a topological space is the minimal cardinality of a basis of the topology. A space $X$ is **extremely disconnected** if open sets in $X$ have open closures.

Is there an example in ZFC of a compact, Hausdorff, extremely disconnected space of weight $\omega_1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**. Weight $\kappa$ of any compact, extremely disconnected space satisfies $\kappa^\omega=\kappa$. This is Corollary 6 in:

B.A. Efimov, Extremally disconnected bicompacta and absolutes, *Trudy Mosc. Mat. Obsh*. **23** (1970) (Russian) English translation: *Trans. Moscow Math. Soc.* **23** (1970) 243-285.